# Improving dependently typed reverse function

Tags: coq

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
Section ilist.
Variable A: Set.

Inductive ilist : nat -> Set :=
| Nil : ilist O
| Cons : forall n, A -> ilist n -> ilist (S n).

(* not sure how to use in irev_aux *)
Lemma same_length: forall n i2, ilist (n + S i2) = ilist (S n + i2).
Proof.
intros.
rewrite Nat.add_succ_comm.
reflexivity.
Defined.

Definition same_length' n i2 (l: ilist (n + S i2)): ilist (S n + i2).
rewrite Nat.add_succ_comm.
assumption.
Defined.

Fixpoint irev_aux i1 i2 (ls:ilist i1): ilist i2 -> ilist (i1+i2) :=
match ls in (ilist i1') return (ilist i2 -> ilist (i1'+i2)) with
| Nil => fun rev => rev
| Cons h t => fun rev =>
    same_length' _ _ ((irev_aux t) (Cons h rev))
end.

Definition same_length'' n (l:ilist (n+0)): ilist n.
Proof.
rewrite plus_0_r in l.
assumption.
Defined.

Definition irev n (ls:ilist n): ilist n :=
  same_length'' n (irev_aux ls Nil).

End ilist.
```

This works! Which is an improvement from my previous attempts :) But there are a couple less than desirable aspects that I'd like to try and refine.

First, having a bunch of proofs hanging out to munge equivalent types seems...annoying. Basically, same_length, same_length', same_length''. Perhaps this is an issue with how I defined irev_aux, but I tried some definitions and others required a type level match which seemed about as annoying.

I tried using refine, but got a type error...is there a way to invoke refine, where you then have to prove that the types are in fact equivalent? In a sense that's what I did, but who wants those lemmas hanging out.

Beyond that, I realize there are probably ways to get rid of the equality lemmas, but I'm curious how I can make use of `same_length`. I've seen cases of matching on equality proofs before to get the typer to unify types...I tried that here but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of programming `irev` without a cast. This is one of the many reasons why Coq users generally avoid indexed data types like this :)

Here is one possibility for writing this function:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.

Definition cast {A B : Set} (e : A = B) : A -> B :=
  match e with eq_refl => fun x => x end.

Section ilist.
Variable A: Set.

Inductive ilist : nat -> Set :=
| Nil : ilist O
| Cons : forall n, A -> ilist n -> ilist (S n).

Fixpoint irev_length i1 i2 : nat :=
  match i1 with
  | 0    => i2
  | S i1 => irev_length i1 (S i2)
  end.

Fixpoint irev_aux i1 i2 (ls:ilist i1): ilist i2 -> ilist (irev_length i1 i2) :=
  match ls with
  | Nil      => fun rev => rev
  | Cons h t => fun rev => irev_aux t (Cons h rev)
  end.

Fixpoint irev_length_plus i1 i2 : irev_length i1 i2 = i1 + i2 :=
  match i1 with
  | 0    => eq_refl
  | S i1 => eq_trans (irev_length_plus i1 (S i2)) (Nat.add_succ_r _ _)
  end.

Definition irev i (l : ilist i) :=
  cast (f_equal ilist (eq_trans (irev_length_plus i 0) (Nat.add_comm _ _)))
       (irev_aux l Nil).

End ilist.
```

If you want to prove anything about `irev`, the easiest is probably to convert the indexed lists to normal lists and reasoning about reversal of normal lists.  Fun exercise: try showing that `irev` is its own inverse.